# For approximately what angles of inclination will the projectile hit the wall or soar over the wall?

Tags: calculus, parametric

On flat terrain, a projectile with an initial velocity of $190$ (ft/sec) is fired at a $20$ - foot high vertical wall $1000$ feet from the tip of the cannon inclined at an angle a with the horizontal.​

We know that:

> $x(t, s, a) = s \,t \cos a$
>
> $y(t, s, a) = -16 t^2 + s\, t \sin a$

Steps I took:

Find when the projectile hits the ground:

$y(t, s, a) = 0$

$t = \frac{s \sin a}{16}$

For a given muzzle speed $s$ and angle $a$ , the horizontal range of the cannon is:

$f(a) = x(\frac{1}{16}\cdot 190 \sin a, 190, a)= \frac{9025 (\cos a)(  \sin a)}{4}$

When $f'(a) = 0$,

$a = \frac{3\pi}{4} \text{ or } \frac{\pi}{4}$

So projectile hits or soars over the wall at angles $\frac{3\pi}{4} \text{ or } \frac{\pi}{4}$. However, this answer is wrong and I am clueless as to how to go about finding the correct answer. What steps do I need to take to find the correct answer?

Comment: Up to where you computed $f(a)$, all's well.  However, the derivative is $0$ for $a=\frac{\pi}{4}$.  That value gives the angle for which the distance is maximum, but it doesn't solve your problem.  One way you can proceed is to eliminate the parameter to get $y$ as a function of $x$ and $a$, and set $x$ to $1000$ to get $y$ as a function of $a$ only.  That gives you the height of the projectile when it reaches the horizontal position of the wall.  Depending on whether that height is negative, between 0 and 20, or greater than 20, you have three conclusions.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Which parameters need to be eliminated?

Comment: The parameter to be eliminated is $t$.  From $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ you get $y(x)$ by elimination.

Comment: How do you eliminate t?

Comment: Write $t = x/(s \cos a)$ and plug it in the expression for $y$.